# Как получить по АПИ только первое значение?

Tags: php, api

Код

```
<?php
$cache_ttl = 21600; // время жизни кэша в секундах
$cache_file_airlines = "tmp/airlines.data";
$cache_file_products = "tmp/products.data";
$map = function ($array, $from, $to) {
    $result = [];
    if (!empty($array) && is_array($array)) {
        foreach ($array as $element) {
            $key = $element[$from] ?: null;
            $value = $element[$to] ?: null;
            if ($key && $value) {
                $result[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
};
if (
    file_exists($cache_file_airlines) &&
    time() - filemtime($cache_file_airlines) < $cache_ttl
) {
    // берём кэшированные данные
    $get_airlines = file_get_contents($cache_file_airlines);
} else {
    $get_airlines = file_get_contents('/json/airlines.json');
    file_put_contents($cache_file_airlines, $get_airlines);
}
$airlines = array_column($data, 'name', 'iata');

if (
    file_exists($cache_file_products) &&
    time() - filemtime($cache_file_products) < $cache_ttl
) {
    // берём кэшированные данные
    $response = file_get_contents($cache_file_products);
} else {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt(
        $ch,
        CURLOPT_URL,
        "https://api.travelpayouts.com/v1/prices/cheap?origin=MOW&destination=AER&limit=30&token=xxx"
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ["X-Access-Token: xxx"]);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    file_put_contents($cache_file_products, $response);
}
$products = json_decode($response, true);
$replace_value = function ($key, $val) use ($airlines) {
    $response = $val;
    switch ($key) {
        case 'airline':
            $response = $airlines[$val];
            break;
    }
    return $response;
};
 ?>


<?php
if (isset($products['data']) && is_array($products['data']))
{
foreach ($products['data'] as $key => $data)
{
foreach ($data as $destination => $row)
{
if (preg_match('/[A-Z]{3}/i', $key))
{
?>
```

Ответ API

```
{
  "success": true,
  "data": {
    "AER": {
      "0": {
        "price": 4500,
        "airline": "5N",
        "flight_number": 239,
        "departure_at": "2021-10-11T13:00:00Z",
        "return_at": "2021-10-21T18:30:00Z",
        "expires_at": "2021-02-25T17:23:00Z"
      },
      "1": {
        "price": 4135,
        "airline": "U6",
        "flight_number": 273,
        "departure_at": "2021-04-26T05:25:00Z",
        "return_at": "2021-04-29T18:30:00Z",
        "expires_at": "2021-02-24T12:42:30Z"
      },
      "2": {
        "price": 7835,
        "airline": "ZF",
        "flight_number": 301,
        "departure_at": "2021-04-02T05:35:00Z",
        "return_at": "2021-04-03T13:05:00Z",
        "expires_at": "2021-02-24T07:54:53Z"
      },
      "3": {
        "price": 14344,
        "airline": "S7",
        "flight_number": 1249,
        "departure_at": "2021-03-05T10:05:00Z",
        "return_at": "2021-03-10T17:55:00Z",
        "expires_at": "2021-02-24T05:22:45Z"
      },
      "4": {
        "price": 32979,
        "airline": "U6",
        "flight_number": 447,
        "departure_at": "2022-01-17T10:00:00Z",
        "return_at": "2022-01-25T03:55:00Z",
        "expires_at": "2021-02-23T16:25:32Z"
      }
    }
  },
  "error": "",
  "currency": "rub"
}
```

Вот так получаю данные

```
<?php echo $replace_value('destination', $key); ?>
<?php echo $replace_value('departure_at', substr($row['departure_at'], 0, 10)); ?>
<?php echo $replace_value('return_at', substr($row['return_at'], 0, 10)); ?>
<?php echo $replace_value('price', $row['price']); ?>
```

Проблема в том, что выдаются все значение всего ответа, а мне надо одно значение самого первого, вот это:

```
{
  "AER": {
    "0": {
      "price": 4500,
      "airline": "5N",
      "flight_number": 239,
      "departure_at": "2021-10-11T13:00:00Z",
      "return_at": "2021-10-21T18:30:00Z",
      "expires_at": "2021-02-25T17:23:00Z"
    }
  }
}
```

Как это реализовать? В `php` не силен.

Comment: Если json переводите в простой массив, то `$result["data"]["AER"]["0"]`

Comment: @ArchDemon Напишите полный ответ и оформите его в ответе.